# Whether redeclare a const static variable outside a class or not

Tags: c++, static, constants, declaration

In C++ Primer 4th **12.6.2**, It recommend to redeclare a const static variable outside a class.

However, The code below passed in gcc 4.6.3.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
    public:
    const static int a = 1;
};

// const int X::a;

int main() {
    X x;
    cout << x.a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Should we redeclare it?

**PS:**

As recommended by *Potatoswatter* I added a function to use const static member as a reference:

```
const int X::a;

void test(const int& a) {
    cout << a << endl;
}

int main() {
    X x;
    test(X::a);
    return 0;
}
```

If we do not include `const int X::a` outside class `X`, it produced error as below

`undefined reference to 'X::a'`

It is a good practise to make a definition outside a class whether const static or not.

Comment: @MattMcNabb But it seems g++ 4.6.3 do not support c++11 unless we add flag `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I just tried `g++ -std=c++98 -pedantic ex12_42.cpp`, It still works. print `1` as a result.

Comment: OK, it seems this code is actually fine, you only have to define the variable if it is not `const`. Sorry, I don't still have a copy of old standard to refer to

Comment: If the object (in this case `X::a`) can be elided away, the compiler can drop the need for it to exist as a stand-alone object. This generally means that nothing makes an lvalue (i.e. named) pointer or reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an exception to that rule for `const static` members that:

1. Are of integer or enumeration type (pointers, references, floats need not apply)
2. Never have their address taken or get bound to a reference

For `static constexpr` members, the type restriction is dropped (or, replaced with those of `constexpr`), and there *must* be an initializer at the in-class declaration.

In either case, the declaration is not considered to be a definition, despite having an initializer, so the object doesn't get an address until it's declared (hence defined) outside the class. For members of a template, that may be done in every translation unit (TU), for members of a non-template class it must be done in only one TU.

Although your example does compile, the practice isn't generally scalable because such variables can't be passed to generic pass-by-reference functions, including perfect forwarding. The book's advice is good.

Standard reference: [class.static.data] §9.4.2/3.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to re-declare it as you have already declared and defined it in the single line:

```
const static int a = 1;
```

However, for `static` data members (including `const static`), if you only give its declaration in the class. You must define the static member outside of the class declaration, in namespace scope. [For example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr038.htm):

```
class X
{
public:
      static int i; // declaration
};
int X::i = 0; // definition outside class declaration
```

Comment: However, My code works when I didn't include `const int X::a;` Is it optional for `const static` and essential for `static`??

Comment: @qingfeng You code works because you already give its definition in this line `const static int a = 1;`.

Comment: `const static int a = 1;` is still a declaration, not definition. Try use its address and not value and you will see. There is a special case in the language which allows using values of static integral/enum/constexpr members without definitions.

Answer (score 2):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static:

> **Constant static members**
>
> If a static data member of integral or enumeration type is declared const (and not volatile), it can be initialized with a brace-or-equal initializer that is a constant expression, right inside the class definition. In this case, no definition is needed:

The compiler is behaving as expected. It's hard to judge the recommendation of "The C++ Primer" without adequate context.

Comment: IIRC, C++11 extends this to any type that has a `constexpr` constructor, not just enums and integers.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone below the paragraph I quoted from the above link, it's said. "If a static data member of LiteralType is declared constexpr, it can be initialized with a brace-or-equal initializer that is a constant expression inside the class definition. A definition at namespace scope is still required, but it should not have an initializer:"